# Need to have left floating div fixed at bottom div with auto height. Here is the jfiddle

Tags: html, css-float, fixed

http://jsfiddle.net/RJXez/259/

```
<div id="parent">
    <div class="left">
    </div>
    <div class="right">
        <p>
            content 1 here is auto height.
        </p>
    </div>
</div>
<div id="parent">
    <div class="left">
    </div>
    <div class="right">
        <p>
            content 2 here is auto height.
        </p>
    </div>
</div>
<div id="parent">
    <div class="left">
    </div>
    <div class="right">
        <p>
            content 3 here is auto height.
        </p>
    </div>
</div>
```

Need to have the red div stretch with the right div while margin top.
Not fixed bottom of browser but the bottom of parent div.

Answer (score 0):

This sounds like a faux column.  There are many solutions on the web.  One way, you could wrap the right inside the left.  Are you looking for something like this?

Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/s_Oaten/9B9yj/

```
<div id="parent">
    <div class="left">
        <div class="right">
            <p>
                content 1 here is auto height.
            </p>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
<div id="parent">
    <div class="left">
        <div class="right">
            <p>
                content 2 here is auto height.
            </p>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
<div id="parent">
    <div class="left">
        <div class="right">
            <p>
                content 3 here is auto height.
            </p>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

1. Make #parent position: relative
2. Make .left position: absolute, top: 20px, bottom: 0px, height: auto
3. Make .right margin-left: 30% (matching width of .left).

http://jsfiddle.net/RJXez/260/

```
#parent {
 width:100%;
    height:auto;
    background-color:#eee;
    display:inline-block;
    position: relative;
}

.left {
    top:20px;
    width:30%;
    height:auto;
    bottom: 0px;
    background-color:red;
    position: absolute;
    display:block;   
}

.right {
  width:50%;
  margin-left: 30%;
  min-height:200px;
  background-color:blue;
  display:block;
  float:left;
}
```